# d3 drag behavior: registering, listening, and triggering distinct types in the drag namespace?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Typing `d3.behavior.drag()` has me confused. I'd like to specify drag types so that different objects trigger different drag events. I'm used to programming with D3 dispatches/namespaces doing the following:

1. registering them with the D3 dispatch object
2. then using something like `.on('click.typeHere')` to listen for the dispatch event
3. and using `dispatch.typeHere(<<data>>)` to trigger the event.

I can't figure out how the normal dispatch procedure applies to drag behavior. For example:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg').append('g')
    .attr('transform','translate(0,20)');
svg.append('rect')
   .attr('height', 50)
    .attr('width', 20)
    .style('fill', 'steelblue');

var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
drag.on('drag', function() {
    console.log('drag');
}).on('drag.type', function() {
     console.log('namespace active');   
}).on('drag.type2', function() {
    console.log('namespace2 active');
});

svg.append('circle')
   .attr('cx',20)
   .attr('cy',0)
    .attr('r',10)
   .style('fill', 'orange')
    .call(drag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<svg></svg>
```

I want the circle to trigger *just* `drag.type` when it is dragged and not the other drags that are registered in the drag behavior namespace. But `.call(drag.type)` isn't supported. What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: I would attach different drag behaviours to the different kinds of objects. For each, you can have a separate `drag` handler that does the appropriate thing.

Comment: I tried declaring multiple `d3.behavior.drag` objects earlier, but all of the types I defined automatically were promoted to the global d3 namespace. For instance in the above example `type` and `type2` would be in separate drag instances, but both would still trigger across all drags, regardless of the object's called drag instance. I can add it to the example code if that's helpful.

Comment: What I mean is something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/o5d102fm/).

Comment: Weird, could have sworn I did the same thing earlier. If you want to paste the jsfiddle as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use different drag behaviours for the different types of objects with the respective drag handlers doing the appropriate thing. This will save you having to mess around with event namespaces:

```
var drag1 = d3.behavior.drag()
.on('drag', function() {
  console.log('drag rect');
});

svg.append('rect').call(drag1);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on('drag', function() {
  console.log('drag circle');
});

svg.append('circle').call(drag);
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o5d102fm/).